# How to detect clicks in header in tableView uitableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to make a program that collapse rows when the header is clicked.

While there seems to be some delegate that works that can detect clicks to table cell there isn't seem to be any delegate that detect clicks to headers.

This is for iPhone application. I mean click to be touch kid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Just replace the header view with your own custom headerview. Then put gesture recoqnizer to that headerview. No body is answering this.